# Using groupby and n_distinct to count NEW unique ids

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

The following code counts the number of unique IDs per year. My question is: how to count the number of *new* unique IDs, i.e., IDs that did not appear in previous years?

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(count=n_distinct(ID))
```

For example, I need to create the variable wanted_count below

| Year | ID | count | wanted_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2000 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2000 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2001 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2001 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 2002 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 2002 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 2003 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 2003 | 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 2003 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

See data below:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 7L, 4L), count = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), wanted_count = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Split the current year from all previous years.  `dplyr::anti_join()` the current year with the previous years.  Then find the `distinct()` IDs in the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(cum_new = cumsum(!duplicated(ID))) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarize(total = max(cum_new), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(
    result = c(first(total), diff(total)),
    total = NULL
  ) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "Year")
# # A tibble: 10 × 5
#     Year result    ID count wanted_count
#    <int>  <int> <int> <int>        <int>
#  1  2000      3     1     3            3
#  2  2000      3     2     3            3
#  3  2000      3     3     3            3
#  4  2001      0     2     2            0
#  5  2001      0     3     2            0
#  6  2002      1     3     2            1
#  7  2002      1     4     2            1
#  8  2003      1     4     2            1
#  9  2003      1     7     2            1
# 10  2003      1     4     2            1
```

---

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Year    ID  count   wanted_count
2000    1   3   3
2000    2   3   3
2000    3   3   3
2001    2   2   0
2001    3   2   0
2002    3   2   1
2002    4   2   1
2003    4   2   1
2003    7   2   1
2003    4   2   1', header = T)
```

Comment: Excellent use of `!duplicated()`(+1). I follow it and figure out a shorter version.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a logical column indicating occurrences of new `ID`, and sum up them in each `Year` group.

```r
library(dplyr)
  
df %>%
  mutate(new = !duplicated(ID)) %>%
  add_count(Year, wt = new) %>%
  select(-new)

#    Year ID n
# 1  2000  1 3
# 2  2000  2 3
# 3  2000  3 3
# 4  2001  2 0
# 5  2001  3 0
# 6  2002  3 1
# 7  2002  4 1
# 8  2003  4 1
# 9  2003  7 1
# 10 2003  4 1
```

Comment: Very clever use of the `wt`!