# Identify count of unique IDs absent in previous period in time-series data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

I have an R dataframe `df` that contains store-level sales data. This is a time-series data with sales by product-store-week combination. I am trying to identify the number of **new** stores a product sells each week. The main variables are `store_id`, `prod_id`, `period`, and `sales`. Sample data is given below:

```
prod_id      period       store_id       sales
12345           1           0001           6
12345           1           0002           8
12345           2           0003           10
12345           2           0004           4
54321           1           0001           5
54321           1           0005           9
54321           2           0001           11
54321           2           0005           7
```

The ideal desired output would be:

```
prod_id      period       new_stores
12345           1             0
12345           2             2
54321           1             0
54321           2             0
```

Note that new stores in period 1 for each product are assumed to be 0.

I saw an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73459604/using-groupby-and-n-distinct-to-count-new-unique-ids), but that doesn't work with my data; not sure what is going wrong.

I tried the following, hoping to get to my desired output eventually, but it is not working out as expected:

```
  new_stores_per_period <- df %>%
  arrange(prod_id, period) %>%
  group_by(prod_id) %>%
  mutate(Prev_Store_Codes = lag(store_id, default = "")) %>%
  mutate(New_Store = !store_id %in% Prev_Store_Codes) %>%
  group_by(prod_id, period) %>%
  summarize(No_Of_New_Stores = sum(New_Store))
```

Any suggestions to fix this code or a different approach are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to achieve your desired result which checks whether stores in period > 1 also sold the product in the previous period:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df %>%
  arrange(prod_id, period) %>%
  group_by(prod_id, store_id) %>%
  mutate(New_Store = is.na(lag(store_id)) & period > 1) %>%
  group_by(prod_id, period) %>%
  summarize(No_Of_New_Stores = sum(New_Store))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'prod_id'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#> # Groups:   prod_id [2]
#>   prod_id period No_Of_New_Stores
#>     <int>  <int>            <int>
#> 1   12345      1                0
#> 2   12345      2                2
#> 3   54321      1                0
#> 4   54321      2                0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(prod_id = c(
  12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 54321L,
  54321L, 54321L, 54321L
), period = c(
  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
  1L, 2L, 2L
), store_id = c(
  "0001", "0002", "0003", "0004",
  "0001", "0005", "0001", "0005"
), sales = c(
  6L, 8L, 10L,
  4L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 7L
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that ought to work:

```r
d <- read.table(
text="prod_id      period       store_id       sales
12345           1           0001           6
12345           1           0002           8
12345           2           0003           10
12345           2           0004           4
54321           1           0001           5
54321           1           0005           9
54321           2           0001           11
54321           2           0005           7
", header=TRUE)

d %>% arrange(prod_id,period) %>%
    group_by(prod_id,period) %>%
    reframe( stores = list(unique(store_id)) ) %>%
    group_split(prod_id) %>% map( ~{
        .x$new_stores <-
            Vectorize(setdiff, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)( .x$stores, lag(.x$stores) ) %>% map_dbl(length)
        .x$new_stores[1] <- 0
        .x$stores <- NULL
        .x
    }) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

It uses lag, but in a slightly different way.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  prod_id period new_stores
    <int>  <int>      <dbl>
1   12345      1          0
2   12345      2          2
3   54321      1          0
4   54321      2          0
```